# How do I hide column name it group heading

Tags: 2007, site-column, grouping

If I group by a column in a library or list, the name of the column is displayed prior to the value.

i.e., ColumnName:ColumnValue or in my case, Discipline:Civil, Discipline:Electrical etc.

How can I hide the Column name so that the the group headings are cleaner?

I'm using MOSS 2007.

Answer (score 2):

Use DataView webpart....u can change XSL the way u want,  but there could be performance impact based on the list items / query :)

Answer (score 0):

You could write a bit of javascript (jQuery) to manipulate the text in the group headings on page load.